# HttpClient.PostAsync knocks out the app with exit code 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, httpclient, .net-4.5, async-await

Everything was working today until it stopped... Below is the minimum source code (I'm using VS 2012 Update 1, .Net 4.5). When I run it, app exits upon calling client.PostAsync() and so it never reaches Console.ReadLine(). Same in debugger, no exception, nothing, exit code 0.

I tried rebooting machine, restarting VS2012 - nothing works.

Again, everything was running today, not sure what changed (no software has been installed etc, all other network apps still work).

Any ideas? I think I'm loosing my mind.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();
    }

    private async static void Run()
    {
        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var headers = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                              {
                                  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("submit.x", "48"),
                                  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("submit.y", "15"),
                                  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("submit", "login")
                              };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(headers);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.google.com/", content);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Your problem is that a program normally exits when its `Main()` method finishes. And your `Main()` finishes as soon as you hit the `await` in `Run()`, because that's how `async` methods work.

What you should do is to make `Run()` into an `async Task` method and then wait for the `Task` in your `Main()` method:

```
static void Main()
{
    RunAsync().Wait();
}

private static async Task RunAsync()
{
    …
}
```

In C# 7.1+ you should use `async Main` instead:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    await RunAsync();
}

private static async Task RunAsync()
{
    …
}
```

Few more notes:

1. You should never use `async void` methods, unless you have to (which is the case of async event handlers).
2. Mixing `await` and `Wait()` in a GUI application or in ASP.NET is dangerous, because it leads to deadlocks. But it's the right solution if you want to use `async` in a console application.

Comment: +1. As a tip, it's easier to do your top-level `try`/`catch` in `RunAsync` rather than `Main`, because `Task.Wait` will wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`.