# Using HttpClient to send file to SharePoint 365 drive

Tags: c#, http, sharepoint

I have a c# Console app that I am trying to upload a file into a drive located in SharePoint Online. Below is the code I have at the moment.

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
 var response = httpClient.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, content).Result;
 var token = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 var accessToken = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessToken>(token)).access_token;
 var fileName = @"c:\data\sample.txt";
 var fileNameEndpoint = @"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveID}/root:/General/sample.txt:/content";
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
 {
     using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
     {
         var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
         content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
         try
         {
             var response1 = await client.PutAsync(fileNameEndpoint, fileContent);
             if (response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully!");
             }
             else
             {
                 Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response1.StatusCode} - {response1.ReasonPhrase}");
             }
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(e);
             throw;
         }
     }
 }
```

I am getting a token, but my issue is that when the PutAsyc is called the code just stops with a return code of 0. The file is not uploaded, no errors are trapped in the exception, and no errors are logged in the Console window.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: You app is closing.  Add a Console.Readline() to end of code.  You may be getting an error but the app is closing before you see any error messages.

Comment: Added Readline after call to PutAsync.......Still nothing.

Comment: The response1 has a status code.  Should be 200 OK when successful and a 400/500 status if there is an error.  What is the status code?  It doesn't appear that you are getting an exception because the Writeline() would output an error.  It is possible the OpenRead is getting an exception and you are not capturing this exception.

Comment: I have a breakppoint on the PutAsync line and the code runs to that. It is just the actual PutAsync method that errors, with no code

Comment: Are you reaching the catch?  If not then a library is capturing the exception and does not have a THROW.  if means either the 1) The Endpoint cannot be found 2) The Endpoint is refusing the connection.  Possibly HTTPS certificate is wrong. 3) The file content is null.

Answer (score 0):

See: [HttpClient.PostAsync knocks out the app with exit code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179981/httpclient-postasync-knocks-out-the-app-with-exit-code-0)

And: [C# HttpClient - PutAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041997/c-sharp-httpclient-putasync)

The problem is `PutAsync`, you are calling the method from a non-async method, the program will terminate before the async method has a chance to complete. Please see the sources above for a code snippet to adjust.

Let me know if this helps.